# Wordpress PHP - Parse Error

Tags: wordpress, php-parse-error

I'm having trouble logging onto the Admin page of my website www.millcroftrealestate.com

It says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE in /home/sting692/public_html/millcroftrealestate.com/wp-config.php on line 90"

Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
 *
 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
 * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
 * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
 * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
 *
 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'sting692_wrdp11');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'sting692_wrdp11');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'wxbnCVNnz5d9');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         '@j?ipQ1nR,yuuCW@Umillcroftrealestate.comAS-{%gQEpSr_+<dyb+>:Yd#nWbetyh~4rmMUap4Q6rZEcZy');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '+hOIBXnJ~C;ftmT([CA|]_wDSmillcroftrealestate.comG<K?#S8{H>//EaLy7]h:jhRfj.K=Usg#g&$9+ox');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'c8K?-u_wU{BZ2yHK_sbOo1@?!millcroftrealestate.com}H<`PM%7^l6VJTY,~DSOJ,zCtVI@Ym$WZi1@5x5');
define('NONCE_KEY',        's5,9YV+%:+HFX#l~ %RE`AZ/pmillcroftrealestate.comUzn<&<R%71t-|[H-L+}AtN9/thH&dMcVM8WN|Q}');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'KUEIq@~d.Tk+~t>1:HS9$8G_*millcroftrealestate.comzG,jcuq2l=7l#KE[-1c)QW3a{LwGi-kwhRVP&]g');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', ';0GoKVCGWIZh:YOa*h[]-T&Dimillcroftrealestate.comnp=:iQ;z$>OkEYNi2@Y`|5-c|n:Jb #}97E?LX7');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'we3RP{hVolwbVh-((L%LEcHKlmillcroftrealestate.com[IaA9<bDvi`h/M:3U7xK8S]A|.Q,2$|*jcOqWNB');
define('NONCE_SALT',       '~<MckLITBiGaIV)497^JDbe-)millcroftrealestate.comG:*}/Prup?HeQMLNLz2kG~d/306X7Noin@gGh7+');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * WordPress Localized Language, defaults to English.
 *
 * Change this to localize WordPress. A corresponding MO file for the chosen
 * language must be installed to wp-content/languages. For example, install
 * de_DE.mo to wp-content/languages and set WPLANG to 'de_DE' to enable German
 * language support.
 */
define('WPLANG', '');

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php’);
?>
```

The line with a parse error according to Komodo is the second last one "require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php’);"

I'm not at all familiar with PHP and thought someone with experience might be able to fix it easily. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php’);` -> `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`

Comment: @aldanux, yes! There are different characters commonly used as single quotes or apostrophes. You can just copy the single-quote from the beginning of wp-settings.php to the end, replacing that different quote character.

Answer (score 1):

Change this `’` with singlequote `'`

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```